How do I set up an airflow environment in github codespaces?
I dont have a personal pc as of now, so i been using library pc and coding with github codespaces.
I installed airflow on codespaces but when i try to do
airflow standalone
it creates admin and password but when i enter the details, shows me bad request, referrer is not the same.
Can you help?
I tinkered with proxy settings in airflow.cfg but not luck

There is a repo that runs Airflow in Codespaces using the Astro CLI. You can clone it here: https://github.com/astronomer/astro-cli-codespaces it has instructions in the Readme for how to run it, the important thing is that you need at least 4 cores. Hope that helps! :)
